# When redirecting between different pages of website in codeiginiter there is white screen which comes for 2 seconds and after that the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, codeigniter

I am having trouble with a website that uses codeigniter, when i redirect from 1 page to another everything is fine except there is a gap of 2 seconds when a white screen is displayed after which the page is loaded.
How can i fix this ?

Comment: show your view and controller ?

Comment: hi ,  [link](http://developingstudio.com/demo/rent2day) this is the homepage and when i click on any listing at homepage.... you can see page is loaded but there comes a blank screen for 2-3 seconds... @NanaPartykar

Comment: Yeah I saw. I think, image loading problem. Not sure. But, may be.

Comment: i don't think its because of image... even if i remove background image.... still there is a blank screen coming for 2 seconds.. @NanaPartykar

Comment: check your javascript you are using window.setTimeout() , this can  delay your page load  try to disable that script and see , proceed by elimination , use firefox network tools (F12 => network) , check java script bugs under console (f12 => network) there are many reasons the page will load after a delay and we cant "guess" what is it without having the full code

Comment: My guess is it's the very large number of css and javascript packages you are loading. These are pretty much blocking page rendering until they download and are ready to execute. This has nothing to do with CodeIgniter. The first thing to try is putting the calls for javascript libraries at the bottom of the html page. Beyond that your probably going to need some sort of javascript packaging, optimization and loading system. For sure, not a trivial exercise.

Answer (score 1):

probably to many HTTP request so browser have problem to load or maybe u have some css or js that blocking browser to render so that provide delay to load page.